# Importing array values in constructor

Tags: c#, foreach

In my main form I have the following code

```
    [ImportingConstructor]
    public MainForm([ImportMany] IEnumerable<AudioPlugin> content)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
        foreach (var listing in content)
        {
            listBox.Items.Add(listing);
        }
    }
```

In my AudioPlugin class I have the following code

```
    [Export(typeof(INAudioPlugin))]
    public class RecordingPanelPlugin : AudioPlugin
    {
        private string _customer { get; set; }

        public void ConnectionString()
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sdf;Password=pass;Persist Security Info=True"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                var comm = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM main", conn);
                SqlCeDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    _customer = (string)(reader["CustomerName"]);
                    Console.WriteLine(_customer);
                }
            }
        }


        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                ConnectionString();
                return _customer;
            }
        }

        public Control CreatePanel()
        {
            return new RecordingPanel();
        }
    }
```

With the code as it is, I'm only getting the last value returned from the SQL query. What am I missing?

Comment: Your observation is correct.  With that code, the only value that you'll get is the last value returned from the SQL query.  Did you mean to append to _customer rather than assign to it in the method ConnectionString?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I knew it was an obvious oversight. However, this didn't work in my situation as my plugin was attempting to assign all query results to a single string. I posted my solution to this problem below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I was over-thinking this problem. I removed the Import/Export from both classes and instead decided to call the query directly in my main form so I could populate the listbox as needed. Then I'm assigning a variable to the listbox.SelectedItem and am passing that over to the AudioPlugin class. Everything is working as expected now, thanks for the suggestions to try and resolve the issue though.

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning the value of the last read element to the variable _customer, you should use a datastructure (like a List) to keep all the elements you're getting and then pass that to the constructor.
Your code should be fixed this way:

```
private List<string> _customers = new List<string>();

        public void ConnectionString()
        {
            using (var conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sdf;Password=pass;Persist Security Info=True"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                var comm = new SqlCeCommand("SELECT * FROM main", conn);
                SqlCeDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader();

                string customer;
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    customer = (string)(reader["CustomerName"]);
                    Console.WriteLine(customer);
                    _customers.Add(customer);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: This will return all of my values in the query, however, this outputs everything on one line. I need the user to be able to select each item from the listbox individually. What needs to change from the above to make this happen?

Comment: I am not exactly sure of the issue you're having.
With the above implementation, you will get a List of strings containing the individual values from the query. You should iterate through the list after the above method returns and add the elements contained in the list one by one to the control you decided to use. As alternative you could do a DataBinding from the List to the Control.